# grep (print) the lines where the third character is 't'

Tags: grep

below are the file contents

```
# cat example.db
LNT_PROFILE
TMP_PROFILE
GMT_PROFILE
nyt_profile
LNX_PROFILE
LOF_PROFILE
ASA_PROFILE
ist_profile
```

I want to grep (print) the lines where the third character is 't', I know we can achieve this by creating a script to get the third character and pass it to the if loop and success condition will print. but i want to do it in the grep using pattern matching.

Thanks

Comment: `grep '^..t' example.db`

Comment: awesome it works, I used -i option since we have uppercase letters
    grep -i '^..t' example.db

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus you can post it as an answer since it is a complete, valid answer.